# Android: what is the use of static wifi ip in android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, ip, wifi

what is the use of setting the static wifi ip address to the phone...is it having some special purpose in communication??
and will it be useful in the socket communication

any type of help will be appreciated

thank you

Comment: It's for those that like to manually configure the networks that they control? And as an app developer you don't care how the address is configured...

Comment: thanks for your reply...if i use my own static ip then will this ip be useful in socket connection??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a static wifi ip address is valid only in the internal n/w its not your public ip the only use is that your local ip within that n/w ll remain same but ll have a dynamic/static accordingly provided by isp as public ip address

and of course it depends on your router config if it allotted that ip to some other device then there ll be a conflict

its just for configuring on special n/w's which do not assign ip automatically

Comment: yap you can but in a wifi n/w only devices connected 2 that n/w can access or you ll have to configure ur router to forward any connection to a particular port to ur ip

Comment: thanks very much...i have to create a application which will assign its own ip address according to some algorithm and then the two device having same application running will communicate to each other over wifi..for that i have to do some socket connection

Comment: or you can just send the latter ip address to some server and find the ip from there

Comment: setting the static wifi ip will be very useful for communication over wifi

Comment: i have to create the p2p connection between two devices...and the application which i am building will know the ip address of the other device also[static wifi ip]

Comment: ofcourse you can do that or display ur current ip adress and manualy enter it in the other device  check this url http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

Comment: thank you for your answer it helped me..so i am now ready to do the udp connection between the two mobile using static wifi ip..right??